# How to debug in iOS real device on React Native project?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm making react-native project, it almost done so I am trying to test in real iOS device. Because I heard that `push notification` is only working in real device.

Okay, when I test it in Simulator, I can launch debugger through `Cmd+R -> Turn on debugger`, but How about real device?

Can I check `console.log` in real iOS device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good idea to test your app on an actual device before releasing it to your users. This document will guide you through the necessary steps to run your React Native app on a device.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 12):

Shake the device (to bring up the same menu you would bring up with `cmd+D`), then tap `debug JS remotely`